# Windows Server 2008 R2 IP Address Binding order

Tags: windows-server-2008, tcpip, ethernet, ipv4

How do I set the order of multiple IP addresses all bound to one ethernet interface?

Answer (score 1):

I ran into this same issue today. It appears that Windows uses the lowest numbered IP address on an interface as the primary interface IP in the route table, no matter what ordered they are specified or added.  I cannot find a source to confirm this though.

In order to add additional IPs to an interface, and be assured that they are not used as the source IP for outbound connections, you must use the following command:

```
netsh interface ipv4 add address "Interface Name Here or Index #" address=x.x.x.x mask=y.y.y.y skipassource=true
```

The key part being `skipassource=true`.

You can confirm this worked correctly with the following command:

```
netsh int ipv4 show ipaddresses level=verbose
```

Unfortunately, you cannot make this change on an existing IP address, so it must be deleted and re-added.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure what you mean by order. If a NIC has been configured with multiple addresses, all the addresses will be valid at the same time. Gateways and dns servers will be ordered though.
[This article](http://www.windowsnetworking.com/articles_tutorials/Understanding-Advanced-TCP-IP-Settings-Windows-2003.html) explains how to configure advanced networking in Windows.

Comment: Thanks, Since assigning some additional ips to the adapter, all requests seem to be coming from one of the secondary ips not the original "primary ip"

Comment: Similar question on Microsoft technet site: [link](http://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/winserverPN/thread/02c3f5d7-ae2d-48d5-b408-62530b628940/). Maybe that will give you a hint.

Comment: thanks I will try the following hotfix http://support.microsoft.com/kb/2386184/ Im running SP 1 so I suppose it wasnt included...

Comment: actually i think was included in SP1, I think its just a matter of running following command to add the additional IP's - "Netsh int ipv4 add address <Interface Name> <ip address> skipassource=true"

Comment: hmm unfortunately there is no way to set this option on an existing IP you have to del and then add again. this is not possible for me.

Comment: Yeah, I believe you are right.

Comment: thats a pain microsoft